# Neo4j SHOW INDEXES is returning indexes for labels and properties that don't exist in my graph DB

Tags: neo4j, cypher

As the title suggests, when I run `SHOW INDEXES` or `CALL db.indexes()` I get results which tell me the index for a node with "Person" label and "born" property, and nodes with the "Movie" label and the "released" property. However, My graph does not have the "born" property on the "Person" nodes, and I also don't have a "Movie" node at all. Any idea why it is returning these results? When I look at the code tab it states that my `Server address` is correctly defined as my database's address, so from that perspective it seems to be fine, but the response/results I get don't make any sense.

Anyone have any idea why this is happening or how I can see the actual indexes/constraints for my DB?

Comment: The [example dataset](https://neo4j.com/developer/example-data/) that comes with Neo4j Browser is called `movies` and has exactly these indexes. Perhaps you're looking at the wrong database?

Comment: Ya I also figured that it must be showing me the Movies database, so I tried to remove it from my Neo4j desktop client in hopes that it would fix it but the issue remains. Also when I make a query on "Person" nodes, it returns the information from my desired DB and not those from the Movies DB.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the indexes yourself if you cleaned out the database or added different data.
The indexes stick around even if there is no more data.

If you want to start fresh you can use:

```
:use system
drop database neo4j;
create database neo4j;
:use neo4j
```